# The following code doesn't update temp_count, a signal.

Tags: vhdl

I have a structured implementation of 10-bit multiplier in which their is one control unit which keeps the track of the states and updates accordingly. Their is a counter named temp_count which should update and tell me whether I have completed the task or not. I wish I could attach the picture of simulation but I can't access it. I will update it later. Here's the code if someone could help me.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity  Controller  is
port (reset     : in std_logic ;
      clk       : in std_logic ;
      START     : in std_logic ;
      LSB       : in std_logic ;
      ADD_cmd   : out std_logic ;
      SHIFT_cmd : out std_logic ;
      LOAD_cmd  : out std_logic ;
      STOP      : out std_logic);
end;
architecture  rtl  of  Controller  is
signal temp_count : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
-- declare states
type state_typ is (IDLE, INIT, TEST, ADD, SHIFT);
signal state : state_typ;
begin
process (clk, reset)
  begin
    if reset='0' then
      state <= IDLE;
      temp_count <= "0000";
    elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
            when IDLE =>
          if START = '1' then
            state <= INIT;
          else
            state <= IDLE;
          end if;
        when INIT =>
          state <= TEST;
        when TEST =>
          if LSB = '0' then
            state <= SHIFT;
          else
            state <= ADD;
          end if;
        when ADD =>
          state <= SHIFT;
        when SHIFT =>
          if temp_count = "1001" then  -- verify if finished
            temp_count <= "0000";      -- re-initialize counter
            state <= IDLE;            -- ready for next multiply
          else
            temp_count <= temp_count + 1; -- increment counter
            state <= TEST;
          end if;
      end case;
    end if;
  end process;
  STOP <= '1' when state = IDLE else '0';
  ADD_cmd <= '1' when state = ADD else '0';
  SHIFT_cmd <= '1' when state = SHIFT else '0';
  LOAD_cmd <= '1' when state = INIT else '0';
end rtl;
```

Comment: I just tried your code on modelsim and it works well to me. Could it be that you forgot the entity is using an "active low" reset?

Comment: for simulation, its always a good idea to initialize all the declared signals to zero. for example temp_count.

Comment: And A. Kieffer 's comment is a good reason to ask for a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in this case demonstrating the problem.